# How to upload file multipart alamofire swift5?

Tags: swift, alamofire, nsurlrequest

I'm trying to send file to the server via multipart. It can be image or an ordinary file. I have some difficulties with URLConvertible usage. As I see Alamofire has such method, which maybe will be useful for me:

```
AF.upload(multipartFormData: <(MultipartFormData) -> Void>, to: <URLConvertible>)
```

but here as you can I can't attach interceptor which will handle 401 error. For this purpose I have created such variable:

```
let manager =  Session(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default, interceptor: CallInterceptor.init(method:HTTPMethod.post))
```

and also created the request:

```
var request = URLRequest(url: Pathes.init(endpoint: "photo").resourseUrl)
request.httpMethod = HTTPMethod.post.rawValue
```

and final usage is attached to photo selector:

```
  func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        guard let fileUrl = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.imageURL] as? URL else { return }
        if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
 
         .....


          manager.upload(multipartFormData: { (formData) in
                formData.append(fileUrl, withName: "photo", fileName: fileName, mimeType: mediaType)
            }, to: request as! URLConvertible).validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
            .responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) in
                print(response.debugDescription)
            })


}

}
```

but as a result my app crashes with such error:

```
Could not cast value of type 'Foundation.URLRequest' (0x7fff85d1dbd8) to 'Alamofire.URLConvertible' (0x7ffb558a5320)
```

I think I have two ways: use another AF method or created another request type. But I can't imagine which method will help me one one side and on another side I don't know how to create URLConvertible. I thought that I can do it in such way:

```
 let urlRequest: Alamofire.URLRequestConvertible = request
```

but the app crashed again. What I did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a `URLRequest` and not a `URL` you need to use the appropriate `upload` overload: `upload(multipartFormData:with:)`.

```swift
manager.upload(multipartFormData: { (formData) in
                formData.append(fileUrl, withName: "photo", fileName: fileName, mimeType: mediaType)
    }, with: request)
```

Comment: but here I also have to use URLRequestConvertible as I see, and also I have to create some multipart data what I don't know how to do. Can you add some more info please?

Comment: No, `URLRequest` conforms to `URLRequestConvertible` already, so there's nothing more for you to do. You could take your existing code and swap `to` to `with`, remove the cast, and be done.

Comment: did you check your code? I tried to send a file and got such errors `unable to determine interface type without an established connection` and  `unable to determine fallback status without a connection`

Comment: as I see it is connected with new ios 13 policy for connections, similar for this https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/123346 do you know how to fix it for alamofire usage?

Comment: That doesn't appear to be an Alamofire issue but a standard system TLS issue. I suggest you look into that.

Answer (score -1):

let PDFUrl = URL(string: "file://(yourdirectoryurl)")
let myData = try Data(contentsOf: PDFUrl! as URL)

```
            let data : Data = myData
            multipartFormData.append(data as Data, withName: "files", mimeType:"application/pdf")
```

Comment: let PDFUrl = URL(string: "file://\(yourdirectoryurl)")
 let myData = try Data(contentsOf: PDFUrl! as URL)
 let data : Data = myData
multipartFormData.append(data as Data, withName: "files", mimeType:"application/pdf")

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32061848)